# Badge Suggestion: Badges can be sorted

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badges

Please allow users more sorting-abilities when viewing the badges tab.

- Allow them to be sorted by class
- Allow them to be seen in order of acquisition:

  Before I can get Famous Question, I need to have the Notable Question, and before that, the Popular Question:

> 1. **Notable Question** - Silver Badge
> 2. **Famous Question**  - Gold Badge
> 3. **Popular Question** - Bronze Badge

The purpose of this is for easier tracking of my next expected badge.